# Difference in IMap and ICache in Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am new to Hazelcast. What's the difference between IMap and Icache in hazelcast? It would be great if some one can provide the uses cases when to use IMap and ICache. Currently I am using IMap to save data in hazelcast cluster, just want to know, what will be use cases for using Icache.

Answer (score 3):

ICache is the JCache (JSR 107 specification) interface implementation. IMap is more like an extension to java concurrent map. If you do not have any requirement to implement the JCache interface, you can use IMap.

Comment: can you explain more please?