# what's the difference between haazelcast Imap and ICache?

Tags: distributed-computing, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap, jcache

I want to know when it's better to use Imap and when to use Icache.
There is a big ambuity to choose between both of them.
I know this question may be a duplicate of [Difference in IMap and ICache in Hazelcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586264/difference-in-imap-and-icache-in-hazelcast) but is it possible to get more details on when to choose one of them.
Both interfaces have some common methods but the way to choose is very difficult.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference in IMap and ICache in Hazelcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55586264/difference-in-imap-and-icache-in-hazelcast)

Comment: as i just said.The answer is not completly clear

Comment: As the referred answer says, if you need a JCache implementation, use ICache. In any other case, IMap will be probably a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to query objects your cache? Do you want more efficiency oriented capabilities for example, pipelining and performing async map operations? Do you want more eviction policies even custom ones? Would you rather send your processing to the cache rather than being limited to shuffle data back and forth? Yes to any of these, then use Hazelcast Maps.